# Can't get bundle argument in fragment from activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bundle

I am very new as android developer(currently PHP programmer).I am trying learn android by following various tutorials from google developer and other websites.

My problem is that i can't get bundle arguments in my fragment which was set in my actvity.

Here is the method of my HomeActivity:

```
public void SelectItem(int possition) {
    Fragment fragment = new FragmentImageList();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    if (possition <= 3) {

        bundle.putString("test_string", "Hello test");
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        FragmentManager frgManager = getFragmentManager();
        frgManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.image_list_frame, fragment)
                .commit();
    }

}
```

Here is my FragmentImageList Fragment:

```
public FragmentImageList() {

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    String strtext=getArguments().getString("test_string");
    Log.d("test string",strtext);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    Log.d(TAG,  bundle.getString("test_string"));
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image_list, container,
            false);
    GridView gridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(new GridViewAdapter());
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

            String url = (String) view.getTag();
            Log.d(TAG,  url);
            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("EXTRA_IMAGE", url);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

My Error log

```
    07-04 22:16:49.908    1200-1200/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
    07-04 22:16:49.908    1200-1200/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid package name : Perhaps you didn't include a PendingIntent in the extras?
    07-04 22:16:50.033  14550-14550/? E/PhotosPlugin﹕ Loading PhotosPlugin
    07-04 22:16:50.480  14620-14620/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sujit.wallpapersnepal, PID: 14620
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sujit.wallpapersnepal/com.sujit.wallpapersnepal.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
    at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
    at com.sujit.wallpapersnepal.FragmentImageList.onCreateView(FragmentImageList.java:37)
    at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2053)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:894)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
    at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
    at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1452)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6005)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2288)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
                at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:115)
    07-04 22:16:52.006  14729-14729/? E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
    07-04 22:16:52.782  14820-14820/? E/ObjectHelper﹕ Can't find method:setCompatibilityInfo
    07-04 22:16:54.497  15063-15063/? E/SysUtils﹕ ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus
    07-04 22:16:54.613    1200-1200/? E/NetworkScheduler.SchedulerReceiver﹕ Invalid parameter app
```

String strtext=getArguments().getString("test_string"); is not working.I also tried 
Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
 Log.d(TAG,  bundle.getString("test_string")); but it's also not working. However, if i comment these bundle lines then app runs fine without errors.  This "test_string" is just a test argument i am trying to make it work.  So, i want to know what mistake i have done that's giving me this error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sujit.wallpapersnepal/com.sujit.wallpapersnepal.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.os.Bundle.getString(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
```

Edited: I am trying to run this app in my Nexus 5 android version 5.1.1

Comment: did you declare the fragment in the layout too?

Comment: @Blackbelt, yes i have declared fragment in my activity_home layout as <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/image_list_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

Answer (score 2):

Consider using the factory methods as like in the [fragments guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) (near the bottom). The reasons for doing so can be found [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9245408/best-practice-for-instantiating-a-new-android-fragment)

In your `FragmentImageList` fragment add the following static method.

```
public static FragmentImageList newInstance(String string) {
    FragmentImageList f = new FragmentImageList();

    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("test_string", string);
    f.setArguments(args);

    return f;
}
```

and amend your `onCreate()` method like so

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString("test_string");
    }
}
```

And in your `SelectItem` method,

```
Fragment fragment = FragmentImageList.newInstance("Hello test");
```

Comment: Thankx for the reply.I tried your solution but it's throwing same error message. I think i can't use bundle anywhere in my fragment. What might be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing this line

**Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();**

to

**String value = getArguments().getString("key");
Log.i("ANDROID",value);**

Also I am not sure, whether you should be getting the bundle and then inflating the view,
do the other way round, first inflate the view and then take the bundle

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(MainActivity.TAG,"Fragment onCreateView()");
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        String value = getArguments().getString("key");
        Log.i("ANDROID",value);

        return rootView;

    }
```